# Create Functions for New Windows in Python

Tags: python, function, tkinter, window, pack

I have a function that creates a new window and updates some values to insert into one of the Entry widgets in the new window, as part of a times table quiz. I then need to create a new function that runs when the submit button is clicked and checks that the user's answer is correct. However, this new function gives me a NameError when it runs because it cannot identify that widgets in the new window, only checking the widgets in the original window. How do I get it to check the widgets in the new window?
Original window:

```
Label(window,text="TIMES TABLES").pack()
game_btn = Button(window, text="Play Game",command=playGameClicked)
game_btn.pack()
```

Function that creates new window:

```
def playGameClicked():
    #create new window
    newWindow = Toplevel(window)
    newWindow.geometry("500x300+0+0")
    Label(newWindow, text = "Times Tables Game").pack()    
    Label(newWindow,text="Question:",font=("Helvetica",10),width=10,).pack()
    question_box = Entry(newWindow,width=30,background="light blue")
    question_box.pack()
    Label(newWindow,text="Your Answer:",font=("Helvetica",10),width=10).pack()
    answer_box = Entry(newWindow,width=50,background="light green")
    answer_box.pack()
    submit_btn = Button(newWindow,text="Submit",width=10,command=submitClicked)
    submit_btn.pack()
    Label(newWindow,text="You are...",font=("Helvetica",10),width=10).pack()
    correction_box = Text(newWindow,width=15,height=1,background="light blue")
    correction_box.pack()

    #new question (all_tables_dict is a long dictionary of 1-12xtables e.g"1*2":2)
    question_box.delete(0,END)
    keys = list(all_tables_dict.keys())
    new_question = random.choice(keys)
    question_box.insert(END, new_question)
```

When the submit button is clicked: (this is the function that doesn't work)

```
def submitClicked():
    answer_box.get(0.0,END)
    try:
        answer = all_tables_dict[question]
        correct=True
    except:
        correct=False
    if correct==True:
        correction_box.insert("CORRECT!")
    else:
        correction_box.insert("INCORRECT!")
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you have to assign widget to `global` variable - to have access to this widget in other function.

Comment: Globals are necessary but there is also error `answer_box.get(0.0,END)`, should be `answer = answer_box.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show full error message and I can't run it so I will guess

All variables created inside function are `local` and they can't be accessed in other functions. You have to inform function that it has to assign widget to global variable.

```
def playGameClicked():
    global answer_box
    global correction_box

    # ... code ...

    answer_box = ...

    # ... code ...

    correction_box = ...

    # ... code ...
```